# Autofilter Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've been trying to filter for 5 values in column O.  These values may or may not exist.
What I've been trying are the two following examples:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sheet1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
            Array("CONS", "MISC", "PFG", "PRT", "TOTE"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
            ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.DELETE
Range("O8").AutoFilter Field:=15
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="=CONS", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=MISC", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=PFG", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="=PRT", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria5:="=TOTE"
        ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.DELETE
Range("O8").AutoFilter Field:=15
```

The first block of code gives me the error: Subscript out of range.
The second gives the error: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Does anyone see what's wrong with these?

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer below for answer to both questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("MISC" _
        , "MISC", "PFG", "PRT", "TOTE", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Range("O8").AutoFilter Field:=1
```

Comment: Thank you!  But I still get the "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I try  this code: ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O$1000").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="=CONS", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=MISC", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=PFG", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="=PRT", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria5:="=TOTE"

Comment: Alrighty, I see your edited answer.  What is the need Field:=1 instead of 15?  Is it just because the beginning of my range is O already?  If it was A:O would field:=15 be necessary?